# simulated turtlebot mapping itself

Tags: navigation, simulation, mapping, turtlebot, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to simulate a turtlebot gmapping with gazebo, a la this tutorial
http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/turtlebot_simulator%282f%29Tutorials%282f%29Building%2820%29a%2820%29Map%2820%29in%2820%29TurtleBot%2820%29Simulator.html

My issue is that although I have gmapping up and running, I can't get anything close to an accurate map because the laserscan appears to be picking up the bot itself. it places an object where the robot was, and then fails to localize due to the object no longer being there once the bot moves.

Is there any way that I can exempt the robot from the scan?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35962/simulated-turtlebot-mapping-itself/) by [Intellethan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2518/intellethan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-06-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-06-07**:
Will you please post a bag file? I'd like to have a look at this situation... Record the tf, scan, odom, imu topics.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-06-07**:
Please post the image of the map in rviz so that i could analyse the issue.

**Comment by [Intellethan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2518/intellethan/) on 2012-06-07**:
I don't know how to post a bag file, but I will if you tell me how.

**Comment by [Intellethan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2518/intellethan/) on 2012-06-07**:
Here is a screenshot of rviz.

[http://imgur.com/qEmcn](https://imgur.com/qEmcn)

As you can see, the room is well mapped, but the robot has left little bits of wall along the path that I drove it. For now it is localized properly, but the more I drive, the more likely these artifacts are to mess with localization.

**Comment by [Intellethan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2518/intellethan/) on 2012-06-07**:
also, note that the little green boxes that represent an object being picked up by the laserscan are also lighting up around the base of the robot. After close analysis the scan appears to be picking up on the four support bars in the robot model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One common solution to this problem is to filter out scans that are less than some minimum distance from the sensor.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Intellethan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2518/intellethan/) on 2012-06-12**:
Do you know of any good method of doing this? I can't seem to find a parameter or file to change to create this filter.

**Comment by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on 2012-10-09**:
You can check the fix that I made: http://answers.ros.org/question/45301/setting-min-depth-in-openni_kinect/